# PHP, Jquery and DOM manipulation

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql

I have a list that's being populated from the database it's sorted using the time field by ASC dates. I'm using the `<?php foreach() :?>` to loop through and populate the list .

```
<li id="events">
Time: <?php echo $venue['time']; ?> 
Event: <?php echo $venue['location']; ?> 
</li>
```

I have a variable in php called ($time_left ) that keeps track of the days left till *each* event begins I calculate this by taking the time field from the database subtracting today's current date with `php date()` **when this reaches 0 how can I remove the expired event from the start of the list and append it to the end.**

This can be done on page refresh I don't need it to be asynchronous.  Can I do this just in PHP with DOM manipulation?  or should I use Jquery and if so how do I pass the $time_left variable from PHP to my Jquery script?

Comment: I would suggets you to create the data structure(an array for example) with all the included values(including your time_left calculated) and then pass that array to the javascript side using `json_encode($myarray)` in php. Later you can do all the dom manipulation that you need in your javascript side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this looks simple enough. I hope i didn't misunderstand something. it should be something like this.

```
foreach($venues as $k => $venue) {
    $passEvents = array();
    $currentTime = time();
    if(($venue['time'] - $currentTime) <= 0) {
        $passEvents[] = $venue;
    } else {
        echo '<li id="events">';
        echo 'Time: '.$venue['time']; 
        echo 'Event: '.$venue['location']; 
        echo '</li>';
    }
}

foreach($passEvents as $k => $venue) {
    echo '<li id="events">';
    echo 'Time: '.$venue['time']; 
    echo 'Event: '.$venue['location']; 
    echo '</li>';
}
```

Comment: I was writing the same thing. That should be the way to go. Except maybe the $currentTime = date(); part ? Shouldn't it be $currentTime = time(); ?

Comment: can you explain what the => does in `($venues as $k => $venue)` ?

Comment: the '=>' is just connecting the array key to the array value.  In this case it is not really needed, but I always keep just in case I could use it in the future.

Comment: you can read more about it here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php